# Unable to Populate Cloudant database for IBM Physio app

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

I'm trying to follow the steps mentioned here to run Physio app: http://lexdcy040194.ecloud.edst.ibm.com/physio_1_0_2/getting_started

I can't perform step no. 5 successfully. It says there to supply a url and password. The url I got after adding a new database in cloudant (Service Credentials) contains the form of usrname:passwrd@host, but if I pass it as is, I get an error: Name or password is incorrect (it also doesn't make much sense to pass it along with -p param indicating password). When trying to pass url as just host I get server_admin access is required for this request.

Any thoughts?

Also, I couldn't find under Service Credentials the value for: CLOUDANT_ACCOUNT.
Thanks in advance for your help,
Eyal

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Getting Started document linked to in the question is severely outdated. I have contacted the team in charge to hopefully sort that out.

Meanwhile, here are updated steps:

1. Create the Cloudant instance in Bluemix
2. Launch the Cloudant 'console'
3. Create a database
4. Copy the code from here: http://pastie.org/private/o70schlbjmum6hvlvocq into a file named "doc_convert.sh".
5. Add this file to your PATH
6. Run the below from a command line window:

   > cloudant_update.pl -d [value of host from the service credentials screen in bluemix] -p [password value from the service crendetials screen in bluemix] -u healthcare_db.json

Comment: I got: invalid URL. I don't know if this helps, but the host I'm using, b30788fd-05c6-40c7-b166-08d5d9dcdc99-bluemix.cloudant.com, is pingable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to further help you. Ready Apps are a thing of the past with no more active development or support and so it is difficult to help here. Either contact IBM directly or find a different app...

Comment: Here's the output from the terminal window: 

mymac:resources admin$ ls -ll /Users/admin/Desktop/IBM/MobileFirst-Related/ 
total 16
.
-rw-r--r--@  1 admin  staff  2443 Jan 28 10:48 doc_convert.sh
mymac:resources admin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/admin/Desktop/IBM/MobileFirst-Related/doc_convert.sh
mymac:resources admin$ ./cloudant_update.pl -d b30788fd-05c6-40c7-b166-08d5d9dcdc99-bluemix.cloudant.com -p <password from cloudant credentials> -u healthcare_db.json 
Invalid URL.
mymac:resources admin$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If they are no longer supported, do you have another example health app which is more up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information I found in the referenced GitHub repo the required information looks like this:

```
//Cloudant properties
CLOUDANT_ACCOUNT=yourUserName
CLOUDANT_USERNAME=yourUserName
CLOUDANT_PASSWORD=yourPassword
CLOUDANT_DB_NAME=theDatabaseName
```

The username and password are in your Bluemix credentials page for Cloudant, the database name is the name you specified for the DB when you created it. None of the values is an URL. Username and account are the same (typically) because multiple users can access a database hosted under a single account.

Comment: +1 for Username and account are the same. Note, the URL is something you obtain from the DB's Service Credentials found in Cloudant.